# How are frames split up in an inverted page table?

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory

For an inverted page table, it's number of entries = number of frames in main memory.

One frame in the main memory, could be shared by two (or more) processes, say process A and process B. Usually this is noted down in process A and process B individual page table. Like process A page 0 maps to frame 1 offset 1-50, process B page 0 maps to frame 1 offset 51-100.

Since an inverted page table, has only one entry per each frame, so how is this frame splitting mechanism noted down? In this example, there is only 1 entry for frame 1, so how can it be split up to contain both process A and process B page offsets?

Comment: Pages are mapped entirely to frames. Presumably, there is a special mechanism for the shared pages, which are the exception.

Answer (score 0):

An inverted page table maps each page frame in physical memory to a list of one or more virtual pages in virtual memory.  There is typically some kind of chaining or pointer to represent this list of virtual pages via a singly linked list.  Since most page frames map to only a single process, this isn't needed for most page frames, but it is there for those where it is needed.

In the systems I am familiar with, there are no offsets.  Each virtual page in virtual memory maps to a page memory in physical memory.  For instance, with 4K pages, a 4K virtual page (4096 consecutive bytes in virtual memory) maps to a 4K page frame in physical memory (4096 consecutive bytes in physical memory).

Comment: Oh ok, so say there are two virtual pages, Process A page 0 which is in frame 1 of main memory, and Process B page 0 which is also sharing frame 1 of main memory. That means that, if I understand correctly, the chained pointer is used to chain these two virtual pages as a list, in the inverted page table entry 1, is that correct?